# jQuery display property not changing but other properties are

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a text editable on clicking it. Below is the code I'm trying. When the title is clicked it shows an input box and button to save it.

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="title-edit">
      <input type="text" name="title" value="Title">
      <button>Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have changed other properties like color or changing the text of the elements and its working, but it is not applying the display property or .show()/.hide() function on the title or edit elements.

Below is my jQuery

```
$(function(){    
    $('.block').on('click', editTitle);

    $('.title-edit button').on('click', saveTitle);

});
function saveTitle(){
    var parent = $(this).closest('.block');
    var title = $('.title', parent);
    var edit = $('.title-edit', parent);
    $(title).show();
    $(edit).hide();     
}

function editTitle(){
    $('.title-edit', this).show();
    $('.title', this).hide();
}
```

Here's the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ywezpag7/

I've added

```
 $(title).html('abcd');
```

to the end to show that other properties/functions are working, but just not the display.

For checking the html change on title element you will have to check the source through developer tools cause the title element is hidden.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: hmm on which event do you want to hide and show it?`

Comment: Just went to the jsfiddle. You hadn't added the JQuery CDN as an external resource, but once I added that it worked fine

Comment: Sorry maybe you had added that, not sure the resources save for other users. But still, it seems to work fine

Comment: @Brae  showing the edit-title element on clicking title class is working fine, But after clicking the save button, It's not hiding the edit-title block and showing the title class.

Comment: @JohnDoe2 The editTitle() is working fine. But in the saveTitle() function after clicking the save button, It's not hiding the edit-title block and showing the title class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the function saveTitle. The first line must stop the event propagation otherwise after this function the editTitle function is called.

The snippet:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.block').on('click', editTitle);

  $('.title-edit button').on('click', saveTitle);

});


function saveTitle(e){
  
  // this line
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  
  var parent = $(this).closest('.block');
  var title = $('.title', parent);
  var edit = $('.title-edit', parent);
  title.show();
  edit.hide();
  title.text($('.title-edit input').val());
}

function editTitle(e){
  $('.title-edit', this).show();
  $('.title', this).hide();
}
```

```css
.title-edit{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="title-edit">
        <input type="text" name="title" value="Title">
        <button>Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue as mentioned already is that your click events are fighting. In your code, the title-edit class is within the block, so when you click on the save button it triggers events for both clicks.

The easiest and, imho, cleanest way to resolve this is to switch your click event to be called on `.title`, and `.title-edit button`. You can also simplify the code beyond what you've got there.

```
$(function(){    
    $('.title').click(editTitle);    
    $('.title-edit button').click(saveTitle);       
});
function saveTitle(){
    $('.title').show();
    $('.title-edit').hide();   
    $(title).html('abcd');
}

function editTitle(){
    $('.title-edit').show();
    $('.title').hide();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ywezpag7/7/

Answer (score 0):

I tried debug your code, and I had seen, that then you click to "Save" button, handled both functions, saveTitle() and editTitle(), and in that order. Therefore, the elements initially hidden, and then shown.